# Обойтись одним контроллером или создать новый?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Ситуация такая. Есть форма которая отображает таблицу

```
# заголовок описание цена.
1 Позиция1  dddddd   3333
```

Доступна она по localhost/all
В uirouter указываю контроллер PositionCtrl

```
....    
.state('board.position', {
      url: '/all',
      controller: 'PositionCtrl',
      templateUrl: 'views/pages/position/pos.html'})
....
```

Тут все хорошо. Далее мне нужно добавить страницу редактирования/добавления позиций 
localhost/all/edit и
localhost/all/new

Роуты:

```
 ....    
    .state('board.position.new', {
          url: '/all/new',
          controller: 'PositionCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'views/pages/position/new.html'})

    .state('board.position.edit', {
          url: '/all/edit:posID',
          controller: 'PositionCtrl',
          templateUrl: 'views/pages/position/edit.html'})
    ....
```

Вопрос возник потому что у меня уже загружены все данные и я могу ими оперировать на стороне клиента без дополнительных запросов к серверу.

То есть: Когда я нажимаю на позицию у меня открывается отдельная страница с формой редактирования, на этой странице я беру id из stateprovider и выполняю http чтобы загрузить данные и заполнить форму. А если все происходит в одном контроллере, то мне не нужно делать http, я могу найти нужный объект по id в массиве где загружены все данные.

Как мне обойтись одним контроллером? 
Правильно ли так делать, или лучше создать еще 1 контроллер и не смешивать все в кучу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Котроллер списка и позиции должны быть отдельными. По поводу загрузки данных, можно передать контроллеру данные, либо сервис может не посылать http-запрос, если данные у него уже есть.

Что касается контроллеров добавления и редактирования - на мой взгляд, хватит одного.

Comment: А как передать контроллеру данные?

Comment: @A50, например через сервис/фабрику и т.д.

Comment: @A50, `ui-router pass parameters to state`.

Comment: @Grundy, что-то сложно. Это ж ui-router.